What is the observer's positon when using the library `perspective`?
I'm trying to use the library perspective for drawing cubes and later, other solids.  I want to be able to use a pic object named cube in perspective, let's say (see the code below), which, taking two arguments, a certain vertex of the cube and its side, draws the cube in the predefined perspective, the unseen faces being different from the seen ones.  (The cube will have its faces parallel to the planes of the coordinate system.)
To be able to do this, I need to know how to obtain the observer's position from the defining elements of the perspective (i.e. vanishing points, azimuth, and elevation).
What I was able to do follows.
One vanishing point

In the above figures, you can see the result when using the perspective with one vanishing point.  The cubes are correctly drawn, since I have found the formulas for the observer's position.  The coordinates of this position depend on the azimuth, elevation, and vanishing point q = (0, b, 0):

obs x = b tan(azimuth)
obs y = b
obs z = b tan(elevation)/cos(azimuth)

The red cube is there, for the time being, to verify the correctness of the formulas.
Two vanishing points
If we consider two vanishing points, these formulas are no longer correct.  This is normal, since both vanishing points should play a role (i.e. a and b in the code below).  But, let us see what we get when using them.

On the black cubes, we can see that the observer's position is not correctly defined, since on the two top cubes, in both figures, the horizontal faces are not correctly shown.  The red cube is there to obtain, by trial and error, the observer's coordinates y and z.
But, in general, I would like to have formulas for the observer's position given by the defining elements of the perspective, that is the two (or three) vanishing points, azimuth, and elevation.  This is the question that I'm asking.
Remark
From the documentation, the azimuth and elevation give the vector (the direction) of the line passing through the origin and observer.  What I don't understand is the distance from the observer to the origin.  For example, in the case of one vanishing point, the distance is b/cos(azimuth).
The code It is the code of the second figure, with \a = \b = 6.  It is rather long since the definition of the pic object for the cube is long.
\documentclass[11pt, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}  % includes xcolor package
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  3d coordinate is/.is choice,
  3d coordinate is/default/.code={\def\tikz@parse@splitxyz##1##2##3,##4,{%
    \def\pgfutil@next{##1{\pgfpointxyz{##2}{##3}{##4}}}}},
  3d coordinate is/perspective/.code={\def\tikz@parse@splitxyz##1##2##3,##4,{%
    \def\pgfutil@next{##1{\pgfpointperspectivexyz{##2}{##3}{##4}}}}}}
\makeatother

%%% cube definition
\tikzset{%
  for cubeInP/.style args={anchor=(#1, #2, #3), side=#4}{% 
    evaluate={%
      int \nFaces, \nVOnFace;
      \nFaces = 6;
      \nVOnFace = 4;
    },
    evaluate={%  coordinates of the vertices
      % In the (xy) plane, the points 1, 2, 3, 4 display the direct
      % sens for the basis $(e_x, e_y)$---it is induced by the
      % 3d-positiv orientation.
      \cCube{1, 1} = #1;
      \cCube{1, 2} = #2;
      \cCube{1, 3} = #3;
      \cCube{2, 1} = #1 +#4;
      \cCube{2, 2} = #2;
      \cCube{2, 3} = #3;
      \cCube{3, 1} = #1 +#4;
      \cCube{3, 2} = #2 +#4;
      \cCube{3, 3} = #3;
      \cCube{4, 1} = #1;
      \cCube{4, 2} = #2 +#4;
      \cCube{4, 3} = #3;
      \cCube{5, 1} = #1;
      \cCube{5, 2} = #2;
      \cCube{5, 3} = #3 +#4;
      \cCube{6, 1} = #1 +#4;
      \cCube{6, 2} = #2;
      \cCube{6, 3} = #3 +#4;
      \cCube{7, 1} = #1 +#4;
      \cCube{7, 2} = #2 +#4;
      \cCube{7, 3} = #3 +#4;
      \cCube{8, 1} = #1;
      \cCube{8, 2} = #2 +#4;
      \cCube{8, 3} = #3 +#4;      
    },
    evaluate={%  indices of vertices for each face and unitary nornal v
      \fRPolyh{1, 1} = 4;
      \fRPolyh{1, 2} = 3;
      \fRPolyh{1, 3} = 2;
      \fRPolyh{1, 4} = 1;
      \nCube{1, 1} = 0;
      \nCube{1, 2} = 0;
      \nCube{1, 3} = -1;
      \fRPolyh{2, 1} = 1;
      \fRPolyh{2, 2} = 2;
      \fRPolyh{2, 3} = 6;
      \fRPolyh{2, 4} = 5;
      \nCube{2, 1} = 0;
      \nCube{2, 2} = -1;
      \nCube{2, 3} = 0;
      \fRPolyh{3, 1} = 2;
      \fRPolyh{3, 2} = 3;
      \fRPolyh{3, 3} = 7;
      \fRPolyh{3, 4} = 6;
      \nCube{3, 1} = 1;
      \nCube{3, 2} = 0;
      \nCube{3, 3} = 0;
      \fRPolyh{4, 1} = 3;
      \fRPolyh{4, 2} = 4;
      \fRPolyh{4, 3} = 8;
      \fRPolyh{4, 4} = 7;
      \nCube{4, 1} = 0;
      \nCube{4, 2} = 1;
      \nCube{4, 3} = 0;
      \fRPolyh{5, 1} = 4;
      \fRPolyh{5, 2} = 1;
      \fRPolyh{5, 3} = 5;
      \fRPolyh{5, 4} = 8;
      \nCube{5, 1} = -1;
      \nCube{5, 2} = 0;
      \nCube{5, 3} = 0;
      \fRPolyh{6, 1} = 5;
      \fRPolyh{6, 2} = 6;
      \fRPolyh{6, 3} = 7;
      \fRPolyh{6, 4} = 8;
      \nCube{6, 1} = 0;
      \nCube{6, 2} = 0;
      \nCube{6, 3} = 1;
    },
    evaluate={%  coordinates of isobarycenters of faces (needed for
              %  opacity and color
      int \f, \j;
      for \f in {1, ..., \nFaces}{%
        \dx = 0; \dy = 0; \dz = 0;
        for \j in {1, ..., \nVOnFace}{%
          \dx = \dx + \cCube{\fRPolyh{\f, \j}, 1};
          \dy = \dy + \cCube{\fRPolyh{\f, \j}, 2};
          \dz = \dz + \cCube{\fRPolyh{\f, \j}, 3};
        };
        \dCube{\f, 1} = \dx/\nVOnFace;
        \dCube{\f, 2} = \dy/\nVOnFace;
        \dCube{\f, 3} = \dz/\nVOnFace;      
      };
    },
    evaluate={%  vertices (not really needed)
      coordinate \A{1}, \A{2}, \A{3}, \A{4}, \A{5}, \A{6}, \A{7}, \A{8};
      \A{1} = (\cCube{1, 1}, \cCube{1, 2}, \cCube{1, 3});
      \A{2} = (\cCube{2, 1}, \cCube{2, 2}, \cCube{2, 3});
      \A{3} = (\cCube{3, 1}, \cCube{3, 2}, \cCube{3, 3});
      \A{4} = (\cCube{4, 1}, \cCube{4, 2}, \cCube{4, 3});
      \A{5} = (\cCube{5, 1}, \cCube{5, 2}, \cCube{5, 3});
      \A{6} = (\cCube{6, 1}, \cCube{6, 2}, \cCube{6, 3});
      \A{7} = (\cCube{7, 1}, \cCube{7, 2}, \cCube{7, 3});
      \A{8} = (\cCube{8, 1}, \cCube{8, 2}, \cCube{8, 3});
    },
    evaluate={%  seen and unseen faces, and in light faces
      int \i;
      real \tmp;
      for \f in {1, ..., \nFaces}{%
        \tmp = 0;
        for \i in {1, 2, 3}{%
          \tmp = \tmp +\nCube{\f, \i}*(\obs{\i} -\dCube{\f, \i});
        };
        if \tmp>0 then {\isSeen{\f} = int(1);} else {\isSeen{\f} = int(-1);};
      };
    }
  }
}

\tikzset{%  for a cube in perspective
  pics/face cubeinP/.style args={face=#1, color=#2}{%
    code={%
      \draw[#2] (\A{\fRPolyh{#1, 1}})
      \foreach \i in {2, ..., \nVOnFace}{%
        -- (\A{\fRPolyh{#1, \i}})
      } -- cycle;
    }
  },
  pics/cube in perspective/.style args={%
    anchor=(#1, #2, #3), side=#4, color=#5}{%
    code={%
      \tikzmath{%
        \lwS = 1pt;
        \lwU = .6;
      }
      \begin{scope}[for cubeInP={anchor=(#1, #2, #3), side=#4}]
        \foreach \f in {1, ..., \nFaces}{%
          \ifthenelse{\isSeen{\f}<0}{%
            \draw[#5!40, line width=\lwU]
            [preaction={fill=white, opacity=.55}] 
            (\A{\fRPolyh{\f, 1}})
            \foreach \i in {2, ..., \nVOnFace}{%
              -- (\A{\fRPolyh{\f, \i}})
            } -- cycle;
          }{}
        }
        \foreach \f in {1, ..., \nFaces}{%
          \ifthenelse{\isSeen{\f}>0}{%
            \draw[#5, line width=\lwS]
            (\A{\fRPolyh{\f, 1}})
            \foreach \i in {2, ..., \nVOnFace}{%
              -- (\A{\fRPolyh{\f, \i}})
            } -- cycle;
          }{}
        }
      \end{scope}
    }
  }
}
%%%

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  in perspective/.style args={azimuth=#1, elevation=#2, p1=#3, q2=#4, r3=#5}{%
    evaluate={%
      \azimuth = #1;
      \elevation = #2;
      \distance = sqrt(#3*#3 +#4*#4);
      \obs{1} = \distance*tan(\azimuth);
      \obs{2} = -\distance; % *cos(\elevation);
      \obs{3} = \distance*tan(\elevation)/cos(\azimuth);
    },  % !!!
    3d view={\azimuth}{\elevation},
    perspective={p={(#3, 0, 0)}, q={(0, #4, 0)}, r={(0, 0, #5)}},
    3d coordinate is = perspective
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[evaluate={%
    \a = 6; % for the first vanishing point
    \b = 6;
    \c = 0;
    \lwU = .3pt; % unseen line width
    \h = 2;
    \dh = 1;
  }, 
  in perspective={azimuth=-5, elevation=45, p1=\a, q2=\b, r3=\c}]
  
  \tikzmath{%
    \rOH = 5.6;
    \rOX = -0.5;
  }

  % cubes
  \foreach \k [evaluate=\k as \fz using {\k*(\h +\dh)}]
  in {0, 1, 2, 3}{%
    \path (0, 0, 0) pic
    {cube in perspective={anchor=(0, 0, \fz), side=\h, color=black}};
  }
  \path (0, 0) pic
  {cube in perspective={anchor=(\rOX, 0, \rOH), side=\h, color=red}};

  % ruler
  \draw[black] (3, 0, 0) -- (3, 0, 10);
  \foreach \k in {0, ..., 10}{%
    \draw (3 -.1, 0, \k) -- (3 +.1, 0, \k) node[right, scale=.8] {\k};
  }  

  % nodes
  \path (-4, 4) node[red, right, align=left]
  {obs's real \\ x and z \\ \rOX\ and \rOH};
  \path (-4, 1) node[right, align=left]
  {obs's defined \\ x and z \\ \obs{1} and \obs{3}};
  \path (-4, -1.5) node[right, align=left]
  {azimuth=\azimuth, elevation=\elevation \\ a=\a, b=\b, c=\c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[evaluate={%
    \a = 6; % for the first vanishing point
    \b = 6;
    \c = 0;
    \lwU = .3pt; % unseen line width
    \h = 2;
    \dh = 1;
  }, 
  in perspective={azimuth=-25, elevation=45, p1=\a, q2=\b, r3=\c}]
  
  \tikzmath{%
    \rOX = -1.89;
    \rOH = 4.5;
  }

  % cubes
  \foreach \k [evaluate=\k as \fz using {\k*(\h +\dh)}]
  in {0, 1, 2, 3}{%
    \path (0, 0, 0) pic
    {cube in perspective={anchor=(0, 0, \fz), side=\h, color=black}};
  }
  \path (0, 0) pic
  {cube in perspective={anchor=(\rOX, 0, \rOH), side=\h, color=red}};

  % ruler
  \draw[black] (3, 0, 0) -- (3, 0, 10);
  \foreach \k in {0, ..., 10}{%
    \draw (3 -.1, 0, \k) -- (3 +.1, 0, \k) node[right, scale=.8] {\k};
  }  

  % nodes
  \path (-2.8, 4) node[red, right, align=left]
  {obs's real \\ x and z \\ \rOX and \rOH};
  \path (-4, 1) node[right, align=left]
  {obs's defined \\ x and z \\ \obs{1} and \obs{3}};
  \path (-5, -1.5) node[right, align=left]
  {azimuth=\azimuth, elevation=\elevation \\ a=\a, b=\b, c=\c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Ok ... is your question still about the observers position? If so, I suggest to clarify it in your question, e.g. at the end.

Done it @MS-SPO!  Is it clearer now?

Thank you. Think so

I was confused by this tikzlibrary as well. Have a look at my question. I personally think that it is better to follow the approach suggested in this article.
